# How combine the columns of arrays in the following way?

Tags: python, arrays

I have some variables

```
    a=[10,12,12,13,15,12,17,15,12,20,10]
    b=[23,25,27,28,21,24,27,25,24,29,21]
    c=[20,22,21,24,27,23,23,34,23,30,23]
    d=[15,17,17,23,24,26,29,25,25,27,12]
    e=[12,12,12,14,12,13,14,13,12,14,15]
    f=[10,08,08,07,08,07,08,09,10,06,08]
    g=[08,05,04,06,07,08,05,04,03,05,06]
```

I now want to create arrays using the first element of all , the second element of all and so on thus

```
    p=[10,23,20,15,12,10,08]
    q=[12,25,22,17,12,08,05]
    r=[12,27,21,17,12,08,04]
```

and so on.. how do I do this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not having your first set as list of list? It would be much easier task then.

Comment: I had considered stacking them vertically and using a transpose. But I do not know how to do that without using numpy arrays. Please help

Comment: I'm new to python sorry. How will it help if I use a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [25]: zip(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
Out[25]: 
[(10, 23, 20, 15, 12, 10, 8),
 (12, 25, 22, 17, 12, 8, 5),
 (12, 27, 21, 17, 12, 8, 4),
 (13, 28, 24, 23, 14, 7, 6),
 (15, 21, 27, 24, 12, 8, 7),
 (12, 24, 23, 26, 13, 7, 8),
 (17, 27, 23, 29, 14, 8, 5),
 (15, 25, 34, 25, 13, 9, 4),
 (12, 24, 23, 25, 12, 10, 3),
 (20, 29, 30, 27, 14, 6, 5),
 (10, 21, 23, 12, 15, 8, 6)]
```

Or, to define `p`, `q` and `r`:

```
In [27]: zipped = zip(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

In [28]: p,q,r = zipped[0:3]

In [29]: p
Out[29]: (10, 23, 20, 15, 12, 10, 8)

In [30]: q
Out[30]: (12, 25, 22, 17, 12, 8, 5)

In [31]: r
Out[31]: (12, 27, 21, 17, 12, 8, 4)
```

---

By the way, in Python a number that starts with a 0 is interpreted as being an octal (a number written in base 8). So `08` is a SyntaxError.